# Manually specify a tunnel gateway for an IPSec VPN Connection (ASA)

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec

I have currently got several VPN's on-premise that are setup on the outside interface and using the default gateway on the interface as an originating source of the VPN tunnel.

Although the outside interface has been configured block of IP's - of which I would like a new VPN I am creating to originate from another IP.

I noticed there is a 'Tunnelled' option under the static routes section that allows you to set a default tunnel - although in my case I would like to have more than one origin for VPN's on the outside interface.

My question is - is it possible to have more than one originating source?

Comment: Might have found the answer to my own question - from http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa84/asdm64/configuration_guide/asdm_64_config/route_static.pdf: You can configure only one tunneled route per device. The tunneled option is
not supported in transparent mode.

Comment: By origin, do you mean that you want the *peer/gateway* address to be a different IP than the one configured on the outside interface; or do you mean that you want the traffic over the VPN to be *translated* behind a different IP than the one on the outside interface?